# List Transformation Using List Comprehension

Tags: python, list

I have a list of `numbers` in Python:

```
[[100, 90, 80], [88, 99, 111], [45, 56, 67], [59, 61, 67], [73, 79, 83], [89, 97, 101]]
```

and I need to transform it to this:

```
[[100, 88, 45, 59, 73, 89], [90, 99, 56, 61, 79, 97], [80, 111, 67, 67, 83, 101]]
```

My code is producing something close but inside of a list I have tuples and my code is not dynamic

```
(list(zip(numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4], numbers[5])))
```

Could somebody please help me make it dynamic and make it a list of lists?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip` this way:

```
print(list(map(list, zip(*numbers))))
```

Output:

```
[[100, 88, 45, 59, 73, 89], [90, 99, 56, 61, 79, 97], [80, 111, 67, 67, 83, 101]]
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped with making it dynamic, but I still have tuples inside of the list. How do I make it a list of lists? Could you please help me with that too? Thank you so much!

Comment: @RaminMelikov Edited mine